# Javascript working in JSfiddle but not in Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I added some javascript to animate the login to appear while sliding in the picture.

I tried the code in JS Fiddle and it works like a charm, but if I copy-paste the code to Chrome or Internet Explorer, nothing happens.

Javascript is enabled on both the browsers.

HTML:
    
    
        
        Homepage

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="Header">
        <nav id="navi">
            <img src="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/79a9ee-1471738072.png" class="logo"/>
            <img src="C:\Users\Hasaan\Desktop\HasaanNEW\Hasaan\Media\Images\menu-icon.png" class="menu-icon"/>

            <ul>        
            <li> <a class="navlinks" href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="navlinks" href="#">About us</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="navlinks" href="#">Our Services</a> </li>
            <li class="last" id="login"> <a href="#">Login</a>
                <div class="dummy">
                <ul>
                <li  class="loginform"> <form method="post" action="">
                  <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
                  <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
                  <p class="remember_me">
                     <label>
                      <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
                           Remember me on this computer
                      </label>
                      </label>
                     </p>
                      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
                    </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>


            </ul>           
            </li>

        </nav>  
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab';

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #808080 ;
    font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff; 
}

.show {
    display: none;
}

.logo{
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 11;
margin-left: -100px;
}

.menu-icon {
    padding: 25px 0 0 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 14;
}

#navi {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

nav :hover {
    background: #2CB4AC;
    transition: background 0.6s ease-out;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px 70px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}

.navlinks {
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-color: #2CB4AC;
}

nav li a:active {
    transform: translateY(1px);
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

nav > ul > li:active > ul {
  display: block;
  align: center;
}

.last a{
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('C:\Users\Hasaan\Desktop\HasaanNEW\Hasaan\Media\Images\menu-icon.png') no-repeat;
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body { max-width: 100%; }


    header {

        position: absolute;

    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul { 

        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        border: none;
    }

    #navi li a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#last a{
    border-right: none;
}

    nav li {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
    }

    nav:hover ul {

        display: block;
    }

.logo{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 11;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

#navi :hover {
    background: #2CB4AC;
    transition: background 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(".last").on('click', function() {
  $('li div ul').toggle('');
});
$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's the Fiddle. Please click the login button and it will change its position.

https://jsfiddle.net/5vs30x6f/

Comment: Maybe you forget to add `window.onload` listener. JSFiddle do it automatically.

Comment: Have you tried pasting the code into your developer console?

Comment: Doesn't look like you are loading jQuery in your html?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your jQuery code in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your code goes here
});
```

You can read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). In general the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed

So your code will be:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".last").on('click', function() {
    $('li div ul').toggle('');
  });
  $('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

and add jQuery in your head section

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks, it worked, but how to set the java up, that the login doesent show at first, only by clicking the login button? Like it should be hidden on page loading, but then appear when klicking on the login button in the bar

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you forgot to add `window.onload` listener because this is the only difference between executing code using JSFiddle and pure Javascript, because JSFiddle automatically execute your code when jQuery is load. You should do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // Your code
});
```

Or you can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kind Sir, it worked. But the code isnt running as exected, the login bar shouldnt be there by default, it should be hidden first, and show up by klicking on login, can you help me out please?

Comment: You have a lot of problems in your code: you cannot load local resource like you did `<img src="C:\Users\...>"`, you have an unexpected closing `</li>` element, you didn't load jQuery properly to your page, you didn't correctly attached CSS to your elements, etc... I just explained why your code works on JSFiddle and not on your local machine, but don't expect from me to completely rewrite your code.

Comment: Oh no, that was not meant this way, im so sorry if i didnt make me clear. I meant only the login popup thing, i know that there should be added a line, saying that the login button is toggled onload once already, But i dont know how to code javascript so if youd do only this one line please? edit: willing to give 5 dollars only for this one line, so you can buy yourself a beer :)

Answer (score 1):

You miss this

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(".last").on('click', function() {
  $('li div ul').toggle('');
});
$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab';

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #808080 ;
    font-family: "Montserrat", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff; 
}

.show {
    display: none;
}

.logo{
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
z-index: 11;
margin-left: -100px;
}

.menu-icon {
    padding: 25px 0 0 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 14;
}

#navi {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

nav :hover {
    background: #2CB4AC;
    transition: background 0.6s ease-out;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px 70px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-style: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}

.navlinks {
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-color: #2CB4AC;
}

nav li a:active {
    transform: translateY(1px);
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

nav > ul > li:active > ul {
  display: block;
  align: center;
}

.last a{
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('C:\Users\Hasaan\Desktop\HasaanNEW\Hasaan\Media\Images\menu-icon.png') no-repeat;
}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body { max-width: 100%; }


    header {

        position: absolute;

    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul { 

        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        border: none;
    }

    #navi li a:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#last a{
    border-right: none;
}

    nav li {
        font-size: 2.5em;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
    }

    nav:hover ul {

        display: block;
    }

.logo{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 11;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

#navi :hover {
    background: #2CB4AC;
    transition: background 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Header">
        <nav id="navi">
            <img src="http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/79a9ee-1471738072.png" class="logo"/>
            <img src="C:\Users\Hasaan\Desktop\HasaanNEW\Hasaan\Media\Images\menu-icon.png" class="menu-icon"/>

            <ul>        
            <li> <a class="navlinks" href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="navlinks" href="#">About us</a> </li>
            <li> <a class="navlinks" href="#">Our Services</a> </li>
            <li class="last" id="login"> <a href="#">Login</a>
                <div class="dummy">
                <ul>
                <li  class="loginform"> <form method="post" action="">
                  <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
                  <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
                  <p class="remember_me">
                     <label>
                      <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
                           Remember me on this computer
                      </label>
                      </label>
                     </p>
                      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
                    </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </li>


            </ul>           
            </li>

        </nav>  
    </div>
</header>
```